# Something similar to split()?

Tags: java, android, string, split

I'm looking to take a string and break it into an array at line breaks (\n) I tried using `split` but that takes away the delimiter. I need the `\n` to be kept at the end of each line if it exists. Does something like this already exist or will I need to code it myself?

Comment: thanks guys! it fixed my problem. I've tried a million times to understand regex, still haven't gotten it down yet.

Comment: You should really have a look at the tutorial that I've linked to as it's the best regex tutorial that I've seen so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried using split but that takes away the delimiter. I need the \n to be kept at the end of each line if it exists.

You can still use it and preserve the line break if you use look-ahead or look-behind in your regex. Check out the best regular expressions tutorial that I know of:
[Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
[Look-Around section of the Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

For example:

```
public class RegexSplitPageBrk {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String text = "Hello world\nGoodbye cruel world!\nYeah this works!";
      String regex = "(?<=\\n)";  // with look-behind!

      String[] tokens = text.split(regex);

      for (String token : tokens) {
         System.out.print(token);
      }
   }
}
```

The look-ahead or look-behind (also called "look-around") is non-destructive to the characters they match.

Comment: Rather than simply saying "you're doing it wrong" -- why not provide the ... solution?

Comment: @debracey: that was the plan all along. I often post an initial answer and then add more to it, in order not to work on questions that get deleted. I hate it when that happens. I also don't like posting code without testing it first.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to @Hovercraft solution with Lookahead assertion:

```
String[] result = s.split("(?=\n)");
```

Further details about Lookahead in http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is just adding the delimiters after splitting

```
String delimiter = "\n"
String[] split = input.split(delimiter);
for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    split[i] += delimiter;
}
```